# Is there a quick and easy way to preview a layout at different screen sizes?

Tags: android, layout

Is there a quick and easy way to see how my application will look on different screen sizes and shapes? Currently, I'm going into the AVD manager, editing my device definition, and then launching a fresh emulator. It takes maybe ten minutes for each one.

They layout is defined entirely from resource files. I don't actually need to execute the app. Is there a faster way to do this?

Edit: I should add: there are some custom widgets in the app.

Comment: Google Firebase Allows you to run your app on every possible android device. However, if you are using a free membership, you can only test on 5 devices and 5 attributes per day

Comment: I avoid that by open desired emulators at same time, 2, 3 or what ever.

Answer (score 3):

While looking at a layout open the "Design" tab or open the "Preview" tab on the side. On the top of the window you will see a list where you can change the layout and orientation. [image]

Comment: I'm still using Eclipse (it's a very old app) and in the Preview tab, I get "The SDK layoutlib version is not supported"

Answer (score 2):

May not solve your entire issue, but it's a good to know.
***If you want to have a preview of a static page*** (not rendered at runtime, like recyclerview), you could use android studio to do that.

[image: screen shot of android studio]

Comment: I'm still using Eclipse (it's a very old app), but if this works, it will be worth importing into Android Studio.

Comment: I would recommend importing into Android Studio regardless since that is the Google-approved IDE of choice. You will get a much more robust tool set than you will with Eclipse and the old plugins.